# Настоящее время PHP

Tags: php

В php можно получить дату date('j F Y'). Но пользователь может поменять время через настройки ОС. Как получить настоящее время?

Comment: обратиться к стороннему сервису времени?

Comment: `поменять время через настройки ОС`  клиент не может менять время на сервере

Comment: Начать стоит с логичного вопроса - получить ЧЬЁ время? `date` использует время сервера, а если вы хотите знать время пользователя, который не на сервере, то пользователь должен сам как-то вам сообщить, какое у него время

Comment: Если вы переживаете, что на самом сервере может быть настроено неправильное время, то тогда спросить время у кого-то, кому вы доверяете

Comment: Если сильно припекает и требуется как-то всегда иметь "актуальное время", то перед выполнением скрипта WARNING не советую это делать повсеместно, опасное занятие END-WARNING можно выполнить синхронизацию времени с ntp например от гугла. Просто ставишь пару утилит и вызываешь команду. Тогда на сервере будет актуальное время, но это может затронуть остальные файлы/программы/проекты, так что аккуратнее!

Answer (score 0):

С date вы получите серверное время, не клиентское.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Для этого необходимо использовать [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php) а конкретно нас интересует [DateTimeZone](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.datetimezone.php)

```
$date_utc = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
echo $date_utc->format(\DateTime::RFC850);
```